# Generating multiple bash scripts in python containing iterable argument

Tags: python, bash, shell

I would like to generate 24 shell scripts using python which will vary in name and the i that is listed in the commands, and write them into 24 separate files. What would be the correct syntax to write everything that is going into "content"?

```
for i in range(1,25):

    with open('run_chr_{0}.sh'.format(i),'w') as f:
       content = [

       #!/bin/bash
       #$ -cwd
       #$ -V
       #$ -N run_chr $i
       #$ -e chr_$i.err
       #$ -o chr_$i.out

       DATA_DIR=___
       bfile=___
       plink --bfile ${DATA_DIR}$bfile.name --chr $i --make-bed --out ${DATA_DIR}$bfile.chr$i\n"

       ]
       f.writelines(content)
    f.close()
```

Comment: This does not look like valid Python code, and it's quite unclear what you are trying to achieve here (due to mixing Python variables with Bash variables: do you expect "$i" to be automatically substituted? Python doesn't do that). You might want to consider reading up on string formatting first.

Comment: @kat At first sight your (unclear) intent could be fulfilled  by a parametrised shell script, change all the `$i` in `content` with `$1`, save `content`'s content in a file, say `run_chr` and give the command  `sh run_chr 13` to operate on dataset #13

Comment: Eerily similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26661804/shell-variables-in-qsub even though the topic is different, at least on the face of it.

Answer (score 0):

There really is no need to write multiple scripts to perform what you request.  If you save the following script as `run_chr` and then run it as `./run_chr 17` then it will run with `i=17`.

```
   #!/bin/bash
   #$ -cwd
   #$ -V
   #$ -N run_chr $i
   #$ -e chr_$i.err
   #$ -o chr_$i.out

   DATA_DIR=___
   bfile=___
   i=$1
   plink --bfile "${DATA_DIR}$bfile.name" --chr "$i" --make-bed --out "${DATA_DIR}$bfile.chr$i"
```